# Low Quality Review Queue - did I cause the "invalidate"?

Tags: discussion, support, review

Relevant post
[getting error when typing string airmon-ng start then my wifi's ext video in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034974/after-typing-airmon-ng-start-wlp1s0-for-air-crack-i-get-the-following-message-an)

It came up in the LQ

- I decided that some editing was necessary for me to decide - which I did outside of the review.
- after the edit it wasn't reviewable any more
- so I looked at the timeline (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1034974/timeline) and found the review "invalidated"

Questions:

1. was this a consequence of my editing?
2. is this unwanted?
3. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Time stamp of you editing and review getting invalidated is the same. So, it has to be because of you editing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to the Stack Exchange networks Source code¹ but that makes perfect sense: what you did was simulate 2 users: one editing in one tab, the other reviewing in another tab, and the one editing improving the post so that it does not need any review any more, thus invalidating the review...

So basically:

Q1: Yes, it's <s>your fault!</s> an unintentional by-product of your own actions.  **;-)**

Q2: Nope, looks perfectly logical

Q3: Edit in the review queue itself...

¹ <sup>Luckily for people without a sense of humour I don't.. **>:-)**.</sup>

Comment: The strange thing: as far as I remember I **did** edit questions directly from the queue and was told not to do this because that dropped them from the queue as well.

Comment: @guntbert There's nothing wrong with editing things from the queue *if you intend it to drop them*. The problem is when people edit things and still want to close them from the queue.

Comment: @Seth My intention was to edit it to be able to decide how to to proceed, **not** to drop it from the queue.

Comment: Yeah... this is supposed to avoid completing the review - I do it all the time! Does it always invalidate the review, or only when the post is flagged VLQ (and therefore "not salvageable by editing")? (cc @guntbert)

Comment: @guntbert: if you want to drop it from the queue, edit it.  If you want to keep it in the queue, don't edit... (even not for a really obnoxious speling eror  **;-)** )

Comment: @Zanna I don't want to try it (without good cause).

Comment: @Fabby thats not really feasible in all cases - when I want to decide on some post it needs to be at least readable for me. Well I **can skip** :-)